# Neo4j Empty Response from /db/data/cypher

Tags: neo4j, neo4jphp

I'm having some issues executing Cypher queries through Everyman\Neo4j.  When the cURL request is     encoded and sent to `http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher`, an Empty response is sent back with a `HTTP 200` status.

I've logged into the terminal and I can see that `neo4j-service` is running on the correct port, I can connect with the `neo4j-shell` and run the Cypher I am trying to execute.  I can also cURL via terminal to a number of endpoints and get a valid response.  It seems Cypher is the only problem.

Here is a dump of the curl config:

```
array(8) {
  [10002]=>
  string(36) "http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher"
  [19913]=>
  int(1)
  [42]=>
  int(1)
  [10023]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(36) "Accept: application/json;stream=true"
    [1]=>
    string(30) "Content-type: application/json"
    [2]=>
    string(26) "User-Agent: neo4jphp/0.1.0"
    [3]=>
    string(14) "X-Stream: true"
    [4]=>
    string(19) "Content-Length: 309"
  }
  [10036]=>
  string(4) "POST"
  [47]=>
  int(1)
  [10015]=>
  string(309) "{"query":"MATCH ..."}"
```

[113]=>
  int(1)
}

I've tried restarting the services and rebooting the server with no success.  There's nothing of interest in the error logs or HTTP logs.

I'm running Neo4j Community version 2.1.5.

Answer (score 0):

I gave this a try on my machine and I'm getting back a response at least for the request I'm sending:

```
<?php
    require('vendor/autoload.php');
    use Everyman\Neo4j\Cypher\Query;

    $client = new Everyman\Neo4j\Client('localhost', 7534);

    $queryString = "MATCH (p:Person) RETURN p LIMIT 1";
    $query = new Everyman\Neo4j\Cypher\Query($client, $queryString);
    $result = $query->getResultSet();

    foreach ($result as $row) {
        echo $row['p']->getProperty('name') . "\n";
    }
```

And then when I run that this is the output I see in ngrep:

    `T 127.0.0.1:55145 -> 127.0.0.1:7534 [AP]
    POST /db/data/cypher HTTP/1.1..Host: localhost:7534..Accept: application/json;stream=true..Content-type: application/json..User-Agent: neo4jphp/0.1.0..X-Stream: true..Content
    -Length: 45....{"query":"MATCH (p:Person) RETURN p LIMIT 1"}
    ##
    T 127.0.0.1:7534 -> 127.0.0.1:55145 [AP]
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK..Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8; stream=true..Access-Control-Allow-    Origin: *..Transfer-Encoding: chunked..Server: Jetty(9.0.5.v20130815)....486
    ..{"columns":["p"],"data":[[{"extensions":{},"outgoing_relationships":"http://localhost:7534/db/data/node/1/relationships/out","labels":"http://localhost:7534/db/data/node/1/
          labels","traverse":"http://localhost:7534/db/data/node/1/traverse/{returnType}","all_typed_relationsh    ips":"http://localhost:7534/db/data/node/1/relationships/all/{-list|&|typ
      es}","self":"http://localhost:7534/db/data/node/1","property":"http://localhost:7534/db/data/node/1/properties/{key}","properties":"http://localhost:7534/db/data/node/1/prope
  rties","outgoing_typed_relationships":"http://localhost:7534/db/data/node/1/relationships/out/{-list|&|types}","incoming_relationships":"http://localhost:7534/db/data/node/1/
          relationships/in","create_relationship":"http://localhost:7534/db/data/node/1/relationships","paged_t    raverse":"http://localhost:7534/db/data/node/1/paged/traverse/{returnType
  }{?    pageSize,leaseTime}","all_relationships":"http://localhost:7534/db/data/node/1/relationships/all","in    coming_typed_relationships":"http://localhost:7534/db/data/node/1/rela
  tionships/in/{-list|&|types}","metadata":{"id":1,"labels":["Person"]},"data":    {"born":1964,"name":"Keanu Reeves"}}]]}
    #####################`

What do I have different to you?